# Error handling for Quandl API

Tags: ruby, quandl

I'm using [Quandl Ruby Client](https://github.com/quandl/quandl-ruby) but sometimes it shows error that reason maybe when there is no code in Quandl.

Error message:

> handle_api_error': (Status 404) (Quandl Error QECx02) You have
>   submitted an incorrect Quandl code. Please check your Quandl codes and
>   try again. (Quandl::NotFoundError)

My code:

```
data = Quandl::Dataset.get("TSE/7959").data( params: {limit:1})
```

I've already set api_key and api_version.

I read the library page but have no idea how to handle this error...

Does anyone have idea?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I reolved this issue ruby's error handling.

```
begin
  data = Quandl::Dataset.get("TSE/7959").data( params: {limit:1})
  return data
rescure => e
  p e
end
```

Thank you!